# Can usage of FLANN come under Machine Learning?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, machine-learning

I have written a program to compute SURF features and then use FLANN(Fast Library for Nearest Neighbour) to match and show the nearest neighbours. Now can the usage of FLANN be considered as using machine learning as it is my understanding that it is a an approximate version of k- nearest neighbour search which is considered as machine learning algorithm(supervised learning).

Comment: Yup is does. No reason I cannot be put under machine learning

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please elaborate in how the learning happens or the steps where it occurs?

Answer (score 1):

You will find mention of methods like FLANN, LSH, Spectral Hashing, and KD-tree (variants) in a lot of machine learning publications.

However, as you said, these methods themselves are not learners/classifiers, but they may often be used within typical machine learning applications. Per your example, FLANN is not a supervised classifier, but it can be used to significantly improve taggers and recommenders.

(That said, this question may be more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or the proposed [Machine Learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26434/machine-learning) forum.)

Answer (score 0):

FLANN is just an approximate nearest neighbor search stucture; that's not machine learning.

But your K-nearest-neighbor classifier that uses FLANN *is* machine learning.